# How do I change/replace fragment on button press?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

While learning about fragments, I tried to make a simple program that would change the fragment within the activity on a button click. Though my program compiles without error, I am unable to change the fragment within the FrameLayout on button click. Any advice as to how to change the current fragment with a button click?

Here is my logic within my MainActivity class: The onCreate method replaces the FrameLayout with a fragment of fragment1 by default.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //You use the FragmentManager to replace the container with an fragment.
    //Get fragment manager
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //add
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragment1 frag1 = new fragment1();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag1);
    //commit change
    ft.commit();
}
```

I have two buttons that are supposed to replace the current fragment with their respective fragment (get fragment1 replaces current fragment with fragment1, get fragment2 replaces current fragment with fragment2):

```
public void getfragment1(View view){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new fragment1());
}

public void getfragment2(View view){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new fragment2());
}
```

Here is my basic XML for the MainActivity class:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open Fragment1"
    android:onClick="getfragment1"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="getfragment2"
    android:text="Open Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is working/not working? (Small note: it's a java convention to capitalize classnames, so Fragment1 is preferred to fragment1.)

Comment: Thumbs up for the small note. Please take a look at the coding conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Okay. So I created two buttons (button and button2) that should respond to the methods getfragment1 and getfragment2 when clicked. The methods are supposed to replace the current fragment within the FrameLayout, but this is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried adding a commit after your replace call (take a look at my answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you simply forgot to commit your fragment transaction.

Try adding a

```
ft.commit();
```

right after your

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new fragment2());
```

Comment: Nice to hear. Sometimes we don't see the obvious and need an uninvolved person taking a look at it ;)